# How can I read a string of 1.000.000 character in c++ using getline()?

Tags: c++, string

I need to read 1.000.000 characters of a string on the same line of input, and I usually use getline(cin,string_name) for all these tasks. But in this case I cannot arrive to these "big" numbers.
How can I solve?

Comment: _",,,But in this case I cannot arrive to these "big" numbers..."_ why not, what error do you get, whats the problem ?

Comment: `std::getline()` is only limited by available memory, so 1000000 chars should be nothing for it to handle. The only thing that could prevent it from doing so is if either `string_name.max_size()` is < 1000000 chars (unlikely, unless you are on an embedded system), or the terminal can't take in 1000000 chars on a single line (more likely). Have you tried reading 1000000 chars from a file instead of from `cin`?

Comment: I've got this issue when i'm trying to resolve a problem of "codeforces" platform. The algorithm work well till the platform puts a line of 1000000 char, because says "Time exceeding error" . So idk if the problem Is really the memory or smth else.

Answer (score 1):

The only thinkg I would do different from normal is reservce space in the string.
That way it does not spend time reallocating space.

```
// 1,000,000 is approx 1M that should not be that big.

std::string   line;
line.reserve(1'000'100) // Tiny bit extra for fun. I bet there is some overhead.
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```